# NextJS Source Maps stopped working on Chrome 92

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, next.js, devtools, source-maps

I did not change my `package.json` nor my `next.config`

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev",
    ...
  }
```

But I now get `react_devtools_backend.js:4049`  in my console on Chrome instead of the file and line of my `console.log`.

On [NextJS DOC](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/source-maps) it says

> Source Maps are enabled by default during development.

I am currently on **nextJS v11.0.0**

Any idea what changes was made which broke the source map ?

It works fine on Firefox though.

Comment: I created an issue on github https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/29073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given from @oleics

> disabling react-dev-tools "fixes" this for me